# Differences between two result sets MySQL

Tags: mysql

Very beginner question but haven't been able to come up with answer after reading various help resources.

I have a table group_affiliations which is a joining table between the tables users and groups. Relevant columns: `Id`, `user_id`, `group_id`. I am doing a data cleanup where users were assigned a group_id based on a location which used to be a 3 character abbreviation of a city but has since gone to spelling out full city (ex: a `group_id` for CHA was previously assigned and now a `group_id` for Charlotte). Most users currently have both `group_id`s associated with their user_id but some still only have the old `group_id` and were never assigned the new one.

What is the most efficient way of finding which ids are in this result set:

```
select user_id from group_affiliations where group_id=OldId;
```

and not in this result set:

```
select user_id from group_affiliations where group_id=NewId;
```

Comment: Are `OldId` and `NewId` fields on `group_affiliations`? If so, if a `NewId` has not been assigned, would it be NULL? Can you add some sample data to the question?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. OldId and NewID aren't fields. I was just using those as a place holder.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 'user_id' 
from 'group_affiliations' 
where 'group_id' = OldId 
and 'group_id' != NewId
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT g1.'user_id' 
from 'group_affiliations' g1
inner join 'group_affiliations' g2 
on g2.'group_id' != NewId
and g2.'group_id' = OldId
and g1.'user_id'=g2.'user_id'
```